# Symbol of infinite length conductive(conductor?) wire with direction of flow of current

Tags: tikz-pgf

I  quoted the below image from [here](https://s-cool.co.uk/a-level/physics/forces-in-magnetic-fields/revise-it/force-on-parallel-wires) .

[image]

I want to draw a symbol which indicates the 2 following factors.

1. A conductive(conductor) wire which has an infinite length.
2. The direction of the flow of current of the wire using symbol of
   cross mark(mouth of miffy) or dot at middle.

I want to achieve it using tikz.

Is there any good way(s) to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset
{% style for arrows
  my arrow/.style={% 
    decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[thick]{>}}},
    postaction={decorate}
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\i in {-1,1}
{% circles and arrows (fields)
  \begin{scope}[x=\i cm]
    \draw[fill=gray!20] (4.2,0) circle (1); % conductor
    \draw[thick,-latex] (5.2,0) --++ (1,0) node[above]{$\vec F$}; 
    \clip (0,-4.2) rectangle (6,4.2);
    \foreach\r in {1.2,1.5,3,4}
      \draw[my arrow=0.625] (4.2,0) circle (\r);
  \end{scope}
}
\draw[my arrow=0.9] (0,4.2) -- (0,-4.2);
% directions
\fill (4.2,0) circle (2mm);
\draw[thick] (-4.2,0) ++  (45:1) --++ (225:2);
\draw[thick] (-4.2,0) ++ (135:1) --++ (315:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use a `\foreach` for the symmetry and other for the different radii. The arrows in the middle of the clipped circles can be done with the help of `decorations.arrows` Ti*k*Z library, and the rest is pretty straightforward, or so I think.

[image]